# JPEG BitmapMetadata save fails with large EXIF thumbnail

Tags: c#, metadata

When I copy Exif metadata from one file to another, where the source file has an EXIF thumbnail of length 65173 bytes and add some new EXIF metadata fields, the JPEGBitMapEncoder Save operation

```
destinationEncoder.Save(destinationStream);
```

fails with the message "Commit unsuccessful because too much metadata changed". If the Exif thumbnail has a shorter length (about 7000 bytes), the save after copying and metadata addition work OK.

If I try to remove the EXIF Thumbnail by uncommenting the line

```
//sourceMetadata.RemoveQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=20507}"); // remove thumbnail data
```

I still get the "Commit unsucessful" message.

How can I add EXIF metadata fields without getting this error message?

```
public void CopyMetadata(string sourceFile, string destinationFile, string sXPTitle, string sXPSubject,
            string sXPComment, bool bAspectRatioNotSet, int Width, int Height, bool bShowErrors = false)
{
    string tempFile = destinationFile + ".tmp3";
    uint paddingAmount = 2048;

    // from http://www.dustyfish.com/blog/copying-jpeg-metadata-using-c-and-windows-imaging-component
    //BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;    // Create backup of the file so you can read and write to different files
    BitmapCreateOptions createOptions = new BitmapCreateOptions();
    System.IO.File.Copy(destinationFile, tempFile, true);    // Open the source file
    //System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, tempFile, true);    // Open the source file
    using (Stream sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
       BitmapDecoder sourceDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(sourceStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);       // Check source is has valid frames
       if (sourceDecoder.Frames[0] != null && sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
       {
           // Get a clone copy of the metadata
           BitmapMetadata sourceMetadata = sourceDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata;
           // modify values
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/xmp/PaddingSchema:Padding", paddingAmount);

           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=256}", Width);
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=257}", Height);

           Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=40091}", _Encoding.GetBytes(sXPTitle + '\0'));// uint=40091
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/object name", sXPTitle);
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/xmp/Description:Description", (sXPTitle + " " + sXPSubject).Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").ToCharArray());// XMP Description

           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=40095}", _Encoding.GetBytes(sXPSubject + '\0')); // uint 40095
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/Caption", sXPSubject.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "));
           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/xmp/Description:Description", (sXPTitle + " " + sXPSubject).Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").ToCharArray());// XMP Description

           sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=40092}", _Encoding.GetBytes(sXPComment + '\0')); // uint 40092

           if (!bAspectRatioNotSet)
               sourceMetadata.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=274}", (ushort)1);

           //sourceMetadata.RemoveQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=20507}"); // remove thumbnail data)
           using (Stream tempStream = System.IO.File.Open(tempFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
           {
               BitmapDecoder tempDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(tempStream, createOptions, BitmapCacheOption.None);             // Check temp file has valid frames
               if (tempDecoder.Frames[0] != null && tempDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
               {
                   // Open the destination file
                   using (Stream destinationStream = System.IO.File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                   {
                       // Create a new jpeg frame, replacing the destination metadata with the source
                       BitmapFrame destinationFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(tempDecoder.Frames[0],
                             tempDecoder.Frames[0].Thumbnail,
                             sourceMetadata,
                             tempDecoder.Frames[0].ColorContexts);                   // Save the file
                       JpegBitmapEncoder destinationEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                       destinationEncoder.Frames.Add(destinationFrame);
                       destinationEncoder.Save(destinationStream);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the maximum segment size in a jpeg is about 64k.

Comment: This would explain why it crashes if I add EXIf entries to take the segment size over 64 K... but why did my attempt to remove the thumbnail data with RemoveQuery not work? Do I need to reset the thumbnail length field as well?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't otherwise help.  Most of your post is beyond my experience.  I just knew there probably was a problem due to the size.